# How do I rename all Scanners or object?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, rename

e.g., I have named my Scanner object *readsir*" throughout my code.

[Scanner *readsir*= new Scanner(new File("word.txt"));]

However, I am worried my professor would expect a different Scanner or object name. Every time I highlight one "*readsir*" in the program, all the "*readsir*"s are highlighted. **So, if i want to change all the "*readsir*"s to *objIn*, is there any way to do that?** I am new to eclipse and java programming so I am sorry if it is too obvious.

**I went through the program and changed all the words manually,** but one of my programs is 700 lines long, so I would like to discover a new way for long programs.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Most IDE's have a refactor/rename functionality that should be able to do this for you

Comment: select the variable -> right click->source->refactor.  Then type in the new name of the variable and press enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the variable -> right click->source->refactor. Then type in the new name of the variable and press enter

Or

Select the variable and press, `Alt+Shift+R`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using eclipse you have a shortcut for that. Highlight the variable name you want to rename and press alt+shift+r, you'll see a box around the name. Rename it and press enter, the name should change everywhere that same variable is used.

If you're using another IDE you'll have a similar solution. Check with a right click or in the menu bar on top and search for a tool named refactor or refactoring.